# I need drivers for my USB Wifi Adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter

Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0471:2126 Philips (or NXP) 802.11 n WLAN

This is the device. When I google it, the first page ( https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb) tells I need firmware-ralink package, but it seems to work only in debian, not in ubuntu. When I try to install firmware-ralink I got this error:

trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/3com/typhoon.bin', which is also in package linux-firmware 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.2

Thanks for the help, I rly appreciate it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Answer (score 0):

Please see:

```
modinfo rt2800usb | grep firm
```

Indeed, this driver requires a firmware file, specifically rt2870.bin. This file has been included in all recent Ubuntu versions for many years. Accordingly, your device should work out of the box without installing any other packages.

If it does not, please run and post the result of the wireless script as outlined in the comments.